# Issues using JQuery SlideToggle

Tags: jquery

Im getting a "Flicker" effect while using SlideToggle:

```
        $("#Box").children().hide();
        $(".Box_Child").stop(true, true).slideToggle(1500);
```

Where there are roughly 10 or so ".Box_Child"

I'm using JQuery 1.9.1
All Browsers produce the effect. The above causes the div to hide, slide up, and then reappear instead of hiding and then sliding down. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SxRQN/1/

Comment: Can you post the HTML and a jsFiddle?

Comment: That code should cause children of box to hide immediately, and then all .Box_Child elements to slowly show or hide depending on their previous state. How is .Box_Child related to #Box? What causes this code to run?

Comment: Indeed it should, but that is the problem, it doesn't. Try running the fiddle, it's run inside a click function in my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the nonsense @Kevin B and @j08691, it seems as though that particular animation did not like the fact that I had the block display listed as important. It was most likely conflicting with the css modification and ultimately the direction of the animation. SlideToggle automatically finds whether your div is positioned up or down.

To fix the fiddle, and my page, I just removed !important.